# How do I drop a mongodb database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Mongodb noob questions!

I want to do something similar to rake db:drop but in mongodb, to clear out the contents of my document.

So far I've found the command db.dropDatabase() but is it right that I have to enter it from the mongodb interactive shell? (Any tips on how to enter the shell would be appreciated, I tried following the instructions over at the Mongodb site but I couldn't get it up and running).

Is there a simpler way to do this from the command line?

**Edit**: I tried typing `mongo` and the shell popped up lol.

Comment: According to http://mongoid.org/docs/rails/rake.html `rake db:drop` should work in a Mongoid project - are you getting any errors?

Comment: ah thanks, it did not occur to me to check the mongoid documentation OR actually try `rake db:drop` - noob mistake!

Comment: I also found `mongo DB_NAME --eval 'db.dropDatabase();'` but your way is obviously much more straightforward. Whoever down voted me I apologize! Hopefully this helps other noobs in my position.

Answer (score 8):

rake db:mongoid:drop

this will work

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of information on the shell here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell

But to Drop a mongodb its .Drop()

Comment: As far as I can tell .Drop() is used more to drop collections. I ended up going to my mongo shell by entering `mongo` at the command line, `show dbs` to list all databases, `use <dbname>` to select the database I wanted to drop and then entering `db.dropDatabase()`.